# Settings for Mintel getting remove from registry

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry

So a bit of background, we have a [Minitel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minitel) system used by costumers to view info on our network, they connect via a VTX plug installed on there PC.

Every now and then the setting for the VTX plug (Keyboard command, user id, etc)  will get removed from the registry, Is there any way to see what removed the settings or is there any way to lock the settings from being removed ? Is there anything else that might cause an issue like this?

I have tried recreating the issue with no luck i have check to see if any of the following cause the issue and they don't : Anti-Virus, Windows Defender, CCleaner, Windows Update. The issue only happens on windows 8.1.

Reg entry path:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MCTEL-SAM\VTXPLUG\Keyboard`
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MCTEL-SAM\VTXPLUG\Security`

If an more info is required let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up removing Full Control permissions from `SYSTEM` on the Reg keys in question leaving only the users admin account with full control, but this is not an ideal solution, If anyone has a better solution share with the class.